# wkhtmltopdf 0.12.4 is not rendering images when 100+ pages are being collated

Tags: linux, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

I am using wkhtmltopdf (version 0.12.4) to render several html pages into a single PDF document.  Each of these html pages has the same logo at the top.  When I run it to collate 50 pages, the logo is properly rendered in the PDF.  Running it with 100 pages seems to cause the logo to not be rendered.  It is not outputting any errors/warnings/notices that an issue is being detected.  Anyone out there have any ideas about what might be happening here?  Is there an option I should be using to prevent this?

Here is an example version of the call that I am making:

```
./wkhtmltopdf -q --page-size "Letter" --orientation "Portrait" -L ".5in"  -R ".5in"  -B ".5in"  -T ".5in" /tmp/foo-*.html /tmp/foo.pdf
```

Note that I am using a wildcard to collect all of the html pages to collate into the resulting PDF.

Comment: It seems to work just fine in version 0.11.0 rc1.  Any ideas what changed between versions to create this issue.  I upgraded to fix the problem where the following was being output:  "QPixmap: Cannot create a QPixmap when no GUI is being used".  0.12.4 certainly solves this warning well.

Comment: Having the same issue. Have you found a proper fix?

Comment: Sorry, no resolution.  I just ended up staying with the old version of the code.